# Error: Post Request in Python

Tags: python, post, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to make a login to http://site24.way2sms.com/content/index.html

This is the script I've written.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://site21.way2sms.com/content/index.html'
values = {'username' : 'myusername',
          'password' : 'mypassword'}

headers = {'Accept':'*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
            'If-Modified-Since':'Fri, 13 Nov 2015 17:47:23 GMT',
            'Referer':'https://packetforger.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/changing-user-agent-in-python-requests-and-requesocks-and-using-it-in-an-exploit/',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'}


data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

I am getting the response from the website. But it's kind of encrypted or something like:

```
��:�����G��ʯ#��C���G�X�*�6�?���ך��5�\���:�tF�D1�٫W��<�bnV+w\���q�����$�Q��͇���Aq`��m�*��Օ���)���)�
```

in my ubuntu terminal. How can I fix this ?
Am I being logged in correctly ?
Please help.

Comment: Most likely, since you've specifically said you will accept gzip encoding, the content is indeed GZip-ped. If you don't want this, don't pass that accept-encoding header.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that helped ! But still I am on the login page itself. How can I log into successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form on that page doesn't post back to the same URL, it posts to http://site21.way2sms.com/content/Login.action.

Comment: What part of code do I need to modify in order to get the "html" of the page after having logged in ?